# i want to triger navigationcontroller when i press button in UIView class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I want to trigger Navigation controller to some other screen when i press the button in UIView class. How can i do this?

//Code for UIView Class in Which Button Iboutlet is created

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonDelegate: class  {
    func buttonTapped()
}

class SlidesVC: UIView {

  var delegate: ButtonDelegate?

   @IBAction func onClickFinish(_ sender: UIButton) {

   delegate?.buttonTapped()

   }

   @IBOutlet weak var imgProfile: UIImageView!

    }

   //ViewController Class code in Which Button Protocol will be entertained

  class SwipingMenuVC: BaseVC, UIScrollViewDelegate {
         var  slidesVC = SlidesVC()

             override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                    slidesVC = SlidesVC()
                    // add as subview, setup constraints etc
                    slidesVC.delegate = self

        }

extension BaseVC: ButtonDelegate {
  func buttonTapped() {

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SettingsVC.settingsVC(), 
            animated: true)

   }
   }
```

Comment: use delegate to do this work

Comment: can you please explain how should i do this ?? or you can post any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more easy way is to use typealias. You have to write code in 2 places. 1. your viewClass and 2. in your View Controller.

in your SlidesView class add a typealias and define param type if you need otherwise leave it empty.

```
class SlidesView: UIView {
typealias OnTapInviteContact = () -> Void
var onTapinviteContact: OnTapInviteContact?

    @IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.onTapinviteContact != nil {
      self.onTapinviteContact()
    }

  }
}

  class SwipingMenuVC: BaseVC, UIScrollViewDelegate {
             override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                    let slidesView = SlidesView()
                    slidesView.onTapinviteContact = { () in
                    // do whatever you want to do on button tap
            }

        }
```

Comment: yes thank you, i done it this way . Thank you for follow up aswell :)

Comment: if this is useful then please mark this as answer. By pressing green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate pattern to tell the containing ViewController that the button was pressed and let it handle whatever is needed to do next, The view doesn't really need to know what happens.

A basic example:

```
protocol ButtonDelegate: class {
   func buttonTapped()
}

class SomeView: UIView {
    var delegate: ButtonDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.buttonTapped()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var someView: SomeView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       someView = SomeView() 
       // add as subview, setup constraints etc
       someView.delegate = self
    } 
}

extension ViewController: ButtonDelegate {
    func buttonTapped() {
        self.showSomeOtherViewController() 
        // or 
        let vc = NewViewController()
        present(vc, animated: true) 
    }
}
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MarriageApp.SwipingMenuVC onClickFinish:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcdaa013e10'
showing this error now

Comment: Add your updated code to your question. It does not look like you have implemented it correctly. You shouldn't be calling `SwipingMenuVC onClickFinish` directly

Comment: please Check the Updated Code??

Comment: Have you connected the IBOutlet and IBActions to the storyboard?

Comment: i have  conected the IBoutlets and conection to View Class not in Controller.